# Nonce to secure web form

Tags: asp.net, cryptography, nonce

I already know what is nonce a little bit, however I still a little bit confuse.

I want to ask, to secure web form (ex: order item), is generated nonce can only be used once or it can be used multiple time but with expiration time?

Comment: A nonce is a *number used **once***. There are many different uses for a nonce in security and cryptography. What is your use? Please [edit] your question to describe it in detail. If you use one nonce multiple times then it isn't a nonce anymore, is it?

Comment: I read the artice from this site: [this](https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/digest-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api-part-1/)

The arctice said nonce has expiration time and can be used more than once.